# Fragment ID or Tag in a ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-identifier

I am currently having a problem accessing a Fragment ID and Fragment Tag. I am currently implementing a Fragment in a TabHost and ViewPager, the new tab is added like this:

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Tab0"),
            Tab0.class, null);
```

And the addTab method is the following:

```
public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am currently having 2 tabs and 2 fragments opened in my activity: Tab0.class and Tab1.class. I want the fragment Id or Tag of Fragment Tab1 so that I can pass a value to it using callback method. Would you please be so kind to help me out with this ?

I have tried the following without luck:

```
public String addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
            TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
            tab.setTag(info);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            mTabs.add(info);
            mActionBar.addTab(tab);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            return tab.getTag().toString();
        }
```

and then later I called out the return String as the Fragment tag but it's always null. Could you please help me out ??????? What should I do to access Tab1 Fragment in the background. Thank you so much for your kind help :( !!

Comment: Have you tried `Tab0 tab0Fragment = (Tab0) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem today. I wanted put a value to my fragment and I can't use the Tag because I used a ViewPager and an Adapter. So i used the method getItem() from my adapter that returns the fragment and i create a method in my fragment.

```
public class SchedulePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
  private final ArrayList<String> mTabs;
  public SchedulePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context mContext) {
    super(fm);
    mTabs = new ArrayList<String>();
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_monday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_tuesday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_wednesday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_thursday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_friday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_saturday)));
    mTabs.add(new String(mContext.getString(R.string.label_sunday)));
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mTabs.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return ScheduleFragment.newInstance(position);
  }
}
```

In the activity I past my value like this:

```
(FragmentNameClass)mSchedulePagerAdapter.getItem(0).setDate("00-00-00");
```